# Copy text to clipboard in android studio code +share

Tags: android-studio

this is the code, it works alright after the user drag to highlight. my question is..how will you initiate the share button so the user can share directly to other applications ie.share via after copied to clipboard? so the user wouldn't close the application before pasting here.Thanks so much

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Life Quotes");
    TextView textView = (TextView) v;
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(textView.getText());
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please check out [ask] for information on how to get the most out of your questions.  For example, you can try [edit]ing your answer to provide code where you have attempted a solution and ran into problems.

Comment: i will do that..Thanks so much